# remove selected columns from SparkR dataframe in R

Tags: r, sparkr

I want to remove a large set of columns from a spark DataFrame. The following code is for R but my data is a spark dataframe not an R dataframe (i.e. d and d2 are SparkR DataFrames and I used join to build d3). I actually have about 1100 columns in d3.

```
d = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=10))
d2=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=10))

d$id=1:10
d2$id=1:10
d3=merge(d,d2, by="id")
colnames(d3)
```

I want to remove all the columns of d2 from d3 except for a few (for example, except for "X16.y" "X17.y" "X18.y" ). The column names each begin with an underscore, for example "_id". I need to do this for the SparkR DataFrame not for a plain R dataframe. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

I mean this in SparkR

```
d = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=10))
d2=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=10))
names(d2)=LETTERS[1:20]

d$id=1:10
d2$id=1:10


write.csv(d,"d.csv")
write.csv(d2,"d2.csv")
ds=read.df("d.csv", "csv", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "NA")
d2s=read.df("d2.csv", "csv", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "NA")
d3=join(ds,d2s,ds$id==d2s$id)
```

Comment: Do you want to replicate the above code for SparkR?

Comment: How can you remove column as column names for d2 and d3 are different?

Comment: The code for SparkR would be to save the d and d2 as csv and then use read.df to read them in as SparkR dataframes. Then I used join to merge them in SparkR.

Comment: It seems that when I did this join, the names remained the same so I should be able to refer to some of the names of d3 using colnames(d2). I want to remove most of those from d3

Comment: I tried as a test, in order to select a subset of d3: d2Col=colnames(d2) and then colstring=paste(as.character(d2Col), collapse=", ")  and then  test=select(d3, colstring),  but got an error about Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`_c0, _id,

Comment: My question is when you perform `merge` operation than `colnames` of d3 is going to change. How can you compare `colnames` of d3 and d2 as `colnames` of both data frame are different?

Comment: Hi. How can I add some new code to this discussion? I don't think I can use the add comment button for this?

Comment: You can edit your question and please provide the detailed information so that one can give the answer to your question.

Comment: As per your updated post, d2s contains 22 columns starting from `_c0, V1 to V20, id` and d3 contains 44 columns starting from `_c0, V1 to V20, id` and again starting from `_c0, V1 to V20, id`. Now if will remove d2s columns from d3 that probably it will remove all the columns. Do you want such output? The column names "X16.y" "X17.y" "X18.y" don't appear in d3.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a case where they have different names. I have re-edited the example so that d2 has names from LETTERS[1:20]

Comment: Now I am confused. It seems that even though I changed the names in the example, I am not getting the changed names in the result?